# Simple Query error message Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I am using MSSQL and I get the aforementioned error message when I try to execute the following query.

```
Select * 
from fa_disp
where dispdt between '2014-10-01' and '2015-09-31';
```

I know there is a simple answer.  When I look at all of the other questions and answers for this error msg they are so complex and involved.  I am new to this so when I tried the examples it still didn't work.  Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Convert/Cast in SQL. Something like:
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, dispdt) between '2014-10-01' and '2015-09-31. Those will be the functions I'd start with.

Also, examine the data your comparing in the query. The field dispdt might not contain the data you think it does or be a malformed date.

Comment: Richard, Thanks for the quick response.  I tried to keep my question simple.  I did try the convert (datetime, dispdt) between '2014-10-01' and '2015-09-31' and I got the error:  Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: The second part of your response is interesting.  I am not sure how I would validate the data.  A simple select * on the table fa_disp produces a column with the dispdt and the dates match the date in the GUI.  How can I determine the date format?

Comment: The date out of range error can come from the month > 12, the number of days more than the month can hold, the entire date being out of range for your SQL version. Like earlier than January 1, 1753. It is more likely that the days are larger than the month can hold, or the month is other than the 12 we have.

Comment: Also, the date format is in your local settings. For the US, it would be en-us if using format function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use language-independent format `yyyymmdd` when you pass datetime literal constants like this:

```
Select * 
from fa_disp
where dispdt between '20141001' and '20150931';
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I remain stumped.  I am still gettiing the following error message using the query provided.  Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help but I also tried that before asking the question.  I am stumped.  None of your suggested query modifications have resulted in a successful query completion.  I thought it was me but I guess this is one that won't be resolved.

Comment: There isn't a 31 September.  Man, do I feel dumb

Comment: >>>There isn't a 31 September<<< :)))